# WIX RNN (Navigation) - Bottom tabs not showing for some Android devices

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I've created an app in React native, which uses the Wix RNN lib.
I got the bottom tabs working great on iOS and whenever i test it on my real Android device and simulator.

However some users now report that the bottom tabs are not showing for them. What could cause this? I'm not able to reproduce the bug my users tell me about, hence why i'm trying SO.

My current setRoot() looks like this:

```
bottomTabs: {
            id: 'BOTTOM_TABS_LAYOUT',
            children: [
              {
                stack: {
                  id: 'HOME_TAB',
                  children: [
                    {
                      component: {
                        id: 'HOME_SCREEN',
                        name: 'HomeScreen'
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  options: {
                    bottomTab: {
                        text: "Assets",
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        icon: require('./Assets/images/tabs/wallet-solidx2.png'),
                        iconInsets: { top: 10 },
                        iconColor: '#646466', //7a7a7d 646466
                        selectedIconColor: '#8E8E91'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
```

Comment: my suggestion don't use bottom navigation u have create custom bottom bar component